# JPEG image manipulator for Node JS (from JPEG file dump)

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, jpeg

I've been searching for an npm module that is converts a JPEG-encoded file into an abstracted format, easy for manipulation. e.g. This format would allow one to easily edit the RGBA value at a given position, and write it back to the buffer, similar to image manipulation libraries in Python / Java.

Searches have yielded such modules from RGB values -> JPEG (https://github.com/pkrumins/node-image), but not from JPEG -> RGB model.  Does such a module even exist?

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: [jpeg-js](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js)

```
// First load Image
var jpegData = fs.readFileSync('grumpycat.jpg');

// Decode Image
var rawImageData = jpeg.decode(jpegData);

// rawImageData => 
// {
//  data: [<red>, <green>, <blue>, <alpha>, <red>, <green>, <blue>, <alpha> ...]
//  width: 400
//  height: 300
// }

// Encode Image
jpegData = jpeg.encode(rawImageData, 50);
```

## Option 2: use [html5-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)

```
function getImageData(url, callback){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(this, this.width, this.height);
        callback(context.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height))
    }
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.src = url;
}


getImageData('<url-to-img>',function(imgData){
    console.log(imgData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-graphics) for graphics modules, there is no much you can use to make your challenge straight forward. And Google is quiet as well.
But.

There is one way I would suggest: use [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas) in order to load image and draw it into canvas. Then you can access pixels using [`getImageData`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/), and do with them whatever you want.

Btw, JPEG does not have **A** channel, only **RGB**, while canvas does have 4 channels (**RGBA**).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GraphicsMagick to convert to RGBA with http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/

The resulting 'format' is a plain RGBA stream for easy manipulation.

Use the same module to export the result to whatever format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  In the end, I gave up.

What worked for me was to write a wrapper for an existing terminal utility, and calling it from the server script.  Works well! (: